# Setting Navigation List items to stick together

Tags: css, html

Assuming that I have this navigation bar

```
<div id = "nav">
        <a class = "menus" href = "#">Home</a>
        <a class = "menus" href = "#">Archive</a>
        <a class = "menus" href = "#">Blog</a>
        <a class = "menus" href = "#">Lab</a>
        <a class = "menus" href = "#">About</a>
      </div>
```

And I have this CSS rule

```
#nav{position:absolute; top:20%;}
.menus{border:1px solid black;}
.menus:hover{background-color: pink;}
```

How would I set each item to stick together? in the given output There is always a spacing in between each navigation items. how would I set them to stick together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways, but the most simple would be to `float` the elements.

```
#nav a {
   float: left;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GgsDv/).

So long as are not inheriting other styles that you haven't posted, this should do it.

The problem is the whitespace between the `a` elements are being rendered as a space. Browsers collapse multiple whitespace to one space when rendering.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ACkq7/).

Comment: It finally worked but out of curiosity is this a proper way you create navigation bars?

Comment: @KyelJmD It's *one* way. Generally, you'd use `li` elements for each element.

Answer (score 1):

do this on your .menu class

```
 .menus
{
  display:block; 
  float:left;
}
```

check this : http://jsfiddle.net/GgsDv/1/

Comment: i removed border apply if you need so.

Comment: `float` automatically makes elements block level, so explicitly defining it isn't necessary.

Comment: sometime it does not goes the same that's why i used this.though you are 100% correct and i admit that :)

Answer (score 1):

The space you see between the items is the result of new lines you put after each `<a>` element in the HTML code. So placing all the links in a single line would solve the problem in the most straightforward way:

```
<div id = "nav">
   <a class = "menus" href = "#">Home</a><a class = "menus" href = "#">Archive</a><a class = "menus" href = "#">Blog</a><a class = "menus" href = "#">Lab</a><a class = "menus" href = "#">About</a>
</div>
```